# How can I init items of a tab?

Tags: c#, events, tabs

I have a form with 2 tabs on it. I can chose the tab viewed after initialization and I need some initial code every time after the tab2 is initialized:

```
public partial class SetupComponent : Form
{
    public SetupComponent(bool tab2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (tab2)
        {
            this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
        }
    }

    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
        textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        textBox2.SelectionStart = textBox2.Text.Length;
        textBox2.Focus();
    }
}
```

if I call this class with **tab2=false** and then click onto tab2, **tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged** is called.

But if I select the **tab2=true** during SetupComponent, I find no possibility to do that code. All the TabControl1_Events I found are too early and I don`t find a matching TabPage2_Event.

How can I manage it?

Comment: I did a work around before by looping through every tab page first to initialize each page, then set the tab back to the first

Comment: sorry i'm not getting your question ,do you want tapPage2 selected in UI in case tab2 = true ?

Comment: @Mohammad: Yes exactly. But also to do code of tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged when tabPage2 is diplayed.

Answer (score 0):

I managed this problem using the Paint_Event:

```
    bool activated = false;
    private void tabPage2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!activated)
        {
            tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
            activated = true;
        }
    }
```

I use the variable because the Paint_Event is called many times.